# How to tell if client is authenticated when using passport-local?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, passport.js

I'm facing a problem when trying to figure out whether a client (React) is authenticated or not to show different pages. I'm aware that passport-local set a cookie with the session id on the client but `document.cookie` returns an empty string.

My passport-local and session setup is pretty standard

```
// --------------- SESSION ---------------
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}))
```

```
// --------------- PASSPORT ---------------
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, (email, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ email }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err)

        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found.' })
        }

        if (user.password !== password) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' })
        }

        return done(null, user)
    })
}))

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(id)

        if(!user)
            return done(new Error('User not found'))
        
        done(null, user)
    } catch (err) {
        done(err)
    }
})

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

So how can I check if the client is authenticated or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a `/auth/user` endpoint on the server that returns `req.user`.